# Solving the Lazy Hobo Riddle

Tags: c++, optimization, beginner, mathematics

I would like help in optimizing this calculation, which is from the [*Lazy Hobo Riddle*](http://www.cs.ucsb.edu/~cappello/courses/10.97s/projects/2/):

> There once were 4 hoboes travelling across the country.  During their
>   journey, they ran short on funds, so they stopped at a farm to look
>   for some work.  The farmer said there were 200 hours of work that
>   could be done over the next several weeks.  The farmer went on to say
>   that how they divided up the work was up to them.  The hoboes agreed
>   to start the next day.
>
> The following morning, one of the hoboes - who was markedly smarter
>   and lazier than the other 3 - said there was no reason for them all to
>   do the same amount of work.  This hobo went on to suggest the
>   following scheme:
>
> - The hoboes would all draw straws.
> - A straw would be marked with a number.
> - The number would indicate both the number of days the drawer must work and the number of hours to be worked on each of those days.  For
>     example, if the straw was marked with a 3, the hobo who drew it would
>     work 3 hours a day for 3 days.
>
> It goes without saying that the lazy hobo convinced the others to
>   agree to this scheme and that through sleight of hand, the lazy hobo
>   drew the best straw.
>
> The riddle is to determine the possible ways to divide up the work
>   according to the preceding scheme.

It basically just involves finding all possible solutions of \$a,b,c,d\$ such that \$a^{2} + b^{2} + c^{2} + d^{2} = 200 \$

```
for(int a = 1;a<=100; a++)
    for(int b = 1; b<=100; b++)
        for(int c = 1; c<=100; c++)
            for(int d = 1; d<=100; d++){
                ++counter;
                if(a*a + b*b + c*c + d*d == 200)
                    cout << "a: " << a << " b: " << b << " c: " << c << " d: " << d << endl;
            }
```

Comment: What is `counter` doing?

Comment: I was counting the iterations.

Comment: You have a hundred million passes through the loop here.  Since 15^2 is already over 200 you really only need 14^4 = 38,416 passes.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Notice how the square of a number `15` or greater exceeds 200? What you can do, is set the interval from `1` to `14`.
There is no advantage in evaluating the same combination over and over again. Realize that the most efficient way is to structure your for loops such that

$$ a  \leq b  \leq c  \leq d $$

In your attempt, you are iterating 38,416 times!

By limiting the interval, you iterate just 2380 times!

One more thing you can do: check and break when \$a^{2} + b^{2} + c^{2} + d^{2} > 200 \$

```
for(int a = 1; a<=14; a++)
    for(int b = a; b<=14; b++)
        for(int c = b; c<=14; c++)
            for(int d = c; d<=14; d++){
                if(a*a + b*b + c*c + d*d == 200)
                    cout << "a: " << a << " b: " << b << " c: " << c << " d: " << d << endl;
                else if(a*a + b*b + c*c + d*d > 200)
                    break;
            }
```

Now you iterate only 1,214 times! This is way more efficient.

Comment: Was currently writing an answer along the same lines on my phone.... but damn that's slow as heck. Nice numbers though +1

Comment: Let us assume a==14 this would result in `196 + b^2 + c^2 +d^2 == 200` this can't happen either. So you can limit the loop by `13`

Comment: Ah, noice. That would cut down the # of iterations by 112.

Comment: A spoon of tar if I may. The proposed solution is \$O(n^2)\$ (4 nested loops upto \$\sqrt n\$ each. Surely we can do better. Build a table of squares (\$O(\sqrt n)\$ time and space). Build a table of pairwise sums of squares (\$O(n)\$ time and space). Find all pairs adding up to target (\$O(n)\$ time, \$O(1)\$ space).

Comment: @vnp how would it fulfill the condition that `a <= b <= c <= d`. If there is an \$O(n)\$ solution, it deserves it's own answer.

Comment: On re-reading the question, OP's answer w/o distinct condition, maybe correct; as *the possible ways to divide up the work according to the preceding scheme*, may be construed to mean *the possible ways to divide up the work **between these 4 people** ...* such that Alice working x hours and Bob working y hours is a different *way to divide up the work* than Alice working y hours and Bob working x hours. But both answers cannot be correct.

Comment: this generates an output different to the OP. If you find a tuple you have also to output all its permutations that are different. Also it doe not make sense to continue the b-loop if a^2+b^2 already >200. Same for the c-loop

Comment: I think it is not a good idea to use a code review to rewrite the whole code of the OP because now a review of the answer code is necessary. It makes more sense to list the possible improvements / problems .

Comment: Thank you.
I realized the solutions were actually given in the assignment and I didn't need to print out all permutations.

Comment: You could even put a break in the b loop if `a^2 + b^2 > 200`, and a break in the c loop if `a^2 + b^2 + c^2 > 200`. This would reduce the number of loops but does have more checks per loop

Comment: even better, you could do it best without using breaks (even the last one) by instead of using `b<=14` in the b loop use `b<=(int)sqrt(200 - a*a)`, replace `c<=14` with `c<=(int)sqrt(200-a*a-b*b)` and `d<=14` with `d<=(int)sqrt(200-a*a-b*b-c*c)`

Comment: @IvoBeckers Check my solution for a similar idea. I made the loops go from big numbers to small to reduce the time spent in comparisons, but essentially it's the same idea.

Comment: @Tibos true, I also upvoted your answer :)

Comment: You can precompute the squares and eliminate multiplies.

Answer (score 40):

One thing you should note is that the fourth iteration is useless. Once you fixed the first 3 variables, you need to find the value for the fourth one that equals to 200 minus the sum of squares of the first 3. You don't have to go through all the possible numbers to check if one of them squared is equal to N, you can simply take the square root of N and check if it's an integer or not.

Another thing to notice is that you get the same solution several times in different order. This can be easily avoided (and avoid a lot of iterations because of it) by ordering the variables.

Finally, you can reduce the number of iterations if you fail early. Once you check a = 15 and see that a squared is more than 200, you no longer need to check higher values for a.

The clever thing to do is order the variables in descending order starting from the highest number that might still result in a solution.

Solution:

```
int N = 200;
for (int a = (int) sqrt(N); a >= 0; a--) {
  for (int b = min(a, (int) sqrt(N - a*a)); b >= 0; b--) {
    for (int c = min(b, (int) sqrt(N - a*a - b*b)); c >= 0; c--) {
      double remaining = sqrt(N - a*a - b*b - c*c);
      int d = (int) remaining;
      if ((d == remaining) && (d <= c)) {
        cout << "a: " << a << " b: " << b << " c: " << c << " d: " << d << endl;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I apologize for possible type related errors, i haven't written C in ages.

**Output:**

```
a: 14 b: 2 c: 0 d: 0
a: 12 b: 6 c: 4 d: 2
a: 10 b: 10 c: 0 d: 0
a: 10 b: 8 c: 6 d: 0
a: 8 b: 8 c: 6 d: 6
iterations: 353
```

Comment: You will find this does not generate the same results as the original. I see were you are going but there is one more step you need to add for you solution. for each found solutions, you also need to find all permutations.

Comment: Actually, the third loop is redundant, too. By [Legendre's three squares theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_three-square_theorem), a number can be expressed as the sum of three squares unless it is of the form `(8m+7)4^n` for integers `m` and `n`. 200 is not of this form (200=8*5*5), so there must be a solution of the form `a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + 0 = 200` and you only need to loop to calculate `a` and `b`; the lazy hobo does no work. (Or, if you're a lazy programmer, you just assert that the lazy hobo knows Legendre's three squares theorem so finds a solution with `d=0`.)

Comment: @DavidRicherby It does not help with finding all the solutions.

Comment: @LokiAstari You are correct. I simply considered that it is enough to provide the numbers that should be written on the sticks, where order shouldn't matter.

Comment: @Tibos Sure, if you want all the solutions Legendre doesn't help much. I'd not noticed that part of the question but I think I'll leave my comment as it's related (and, I think, interesting).

Comment: I may have done something wrong, but I found that using `sqrt` actually slowed my implementation down a bit. Iterating from `c` up to 14 is so fast that I don't think `sqrt` is actually a performance win.

Comment: sqrt is expensive.  I would fill a 1..200 array with zeros and then for 1..14 assign the slot with the square to the value.  Get 200 -a^2-b^2-c^2, if the entry is non-zero it's d, otherwise there's no answer for that a, b, c.

Comment: @LorenPechtel That's a clever solution and considering how the time complexity is O(N^3), an O(N) spatial complexity wouldn't hurt. Maybe you should post it as an answer?

Comment: @Tibos My C is so rusty that I would not want to try posting code.

Answer (score 17):

Some minor things, but may still be worth mentioning:

[Whenever `std::endl` is used, the buffer gets flushed, which can add to performance a bit, especially if it's done multiple times.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8311177/1950231)

In order to get a newline without this added flush, use `"\n"` within an output statement:

```
std::cout << "\n";
```

Also, consider adding a bit more whitespace within the multiple loop statements for added readability:

```
for (int a = 1; a <= 100; a++)
```

Comment: Namespace std is used... that's usually not good, right? ?

Comment: @Vogel612: Yeah, but I didn't mention it here since it's an even minor point.

Answer (score 14):

As well as the excellent information from @EngieOP, you could also think about taking some repeated calculations out of the inner loop at the cost of an extra int per 'for' loop.  These might be optimised by the compiler, but it shouldn't reduce clarity.

```
for(int a = 1; a<=14; a++){
    sum_a = a*a;
    for(int b = a; b<=14; b++){
        sum_b = sum_a + b*b;
        for(int c = b; c<=14; c++){
            sum_c = sum_b + c*c;
/*[... etc ...] */
```

It won't reduce the number of iterations, but could reduce the number of cycles in the inner loop to a single add and compare (if the compiler doesn't already catch the optimisation and do it for you)

Comment: We can extend this approach to reduce the number of iterations by adding a small test to the inner for-loops, i.e.
`for(int c = 1; c<=14 && sumB < 200; c++)` and `for(int d = 1; d<=14 && sumC < 200; d++)`.
Done this way, the search produces the same result with 17,458 iterations instead of 38,416.

Answer (score 14):

**Style**

Vogel612 raises an interesting point in [his comment](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/65163/solving-the-lazy-hobo-riddle#comment119484_65165) : `using namespace std;` is usually [considered a bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).

Also, you should try to avoid having the same number hardcoded in different places : you could just use `const int lim = 200;`. It makes things easier to read/understand and easier to maintain : win-win !

**Optimisation**

Riding on [EngieOP](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/65164/9452) (and a bit on [rolinger](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/65178/9452))'s answers : you can limit yourself to :

$$ a  \leq b  \leq c  \leq d $$

This leads to interesting conclusions to be found :

$$ 4 * a^{2} \leq a^{2}  + b^{2}  + c^{2}  + d^{2} = 200 $$
so $$ a^{2} \leq 50 $$
so $$ a \leq 7 $$

We can take this advantage in code by stopping when we know there is no hope to find more.

Let's forget about math and write this thing in simple C++ (storing the different computed values in variable for reuse) :

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    const int lim = 200;
    std::cout << "Hello, world!" << std::endl;
    for(int a = 1; 4*a*a <= lim; a++)
    {
        int tmp1 = a*a;
        for(int b = a; tmp1 + 3*b*b <= lim; b++)
        {
            int tmp2 = tmp1 + b*b;
            for(int c = b; tmp2 + 2*c*c <= lim; c++)
            {
                int tmp3 = tmp2 + c*c;
                for(int d = c; tmp3 + d*d <= lim; d++){
                    if (tmp3 + d*d == lim)
                        std::cout << "a: " << a << " b: " << b << " c: " << c << " d: " << d << std::endl;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**More optimisations for you to consider**

When `a`, `b` and `c` are fixed, looking for `d` could be optimised even more : we want to solve

$$ d^{2} = lim - (a^{2} + b^{2} + c^{2}) $$

You can just compute the root and see if it corresponds to an integer bigger than `c`.

Answer (score 11):

After reading the [John's comment](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/65163/solving-the-lazy-hobo-riddle#comment119502_65164) I thought we can do much better than [EngieOP's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/65164/29371)

> ```
> for(int a = 1; a<=14; a++)
>     for(int b = a; b<=14; b++)
>         for(int c = b; c<=14; c++)
>             for(int d = c; d<=14; d++){
>                 if(a*a + b*b + c*c + d*d == 200)
>                     cout << "a: " << a << " b: " << b << " c: " << c << " d: " << d << endl;
>                 else if(a*a + b*b + c*c + d*d > 200)
>                     break;
>             }
> ```

How to speed this up ? Reduce the calculations !

```
int resultToReach = 200;
int maxBorder = (int)sqrt(200);
for(int a = 1; a<=maxBorder ; a++)
    for(int b = a; b<=maxBorder ; b++)
        for(int c = b; c<=maxBorder ; c++)
            for(int d = c; d<=maxBorder ; d++){
                int tempResult = a*a + b*b + c*c + d*d;
                if(tempResult == resultToReach)
                    cout << "a: " << a << " b: " << b << " c: " << c << " d: " << d << endl;
                else if(tempResult > resultToReach)
                    break;
            }
```

But in this way we still calculate `a*a + b*b + c*c + d*d` for each iteration. So let us reduce them like [rolinger's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/65178/29371) already shows

```
    int resultToReach = 200;
    int maxBorder = (int)sqrt(resultToReach);
    for (int a = 1; a <= maxBorder; a++)
    {
        int firstResult = resultToReach - a * a;
        for (int b = a; b <= maxBorder; b++)
        {
            int secondResult = firstResult - b * b;
            for (int c = b; c <= maxBorder; c++)
            {
                int thirdResult = secondResult - c * c;
                for (int d = c; d <= maxBorder; d++)
                {
                    int tempResult = thirdResult - d * d;
                    if (tempResult == 0)
                    {
                        cout << "a: " << a << " b: " << b << " c: " << c << " d: " << d << endl;
                        break;
                    }
                    else if (tempResult < 0)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

If we now reverse the loops and also adding some minor conditions we will get this

```
    int resultToReach = 200;
    int maxBorder = (int)sqrt(resultToReach);

    for (int a = maxBorder; a >= 1; a--)
    {
        int firstResult = resultToReach - a * a;
        if (firstResult >= 3)
        {
            for (int b = a; b >= 1; b--)
            {
                int secondResult = firstResult - b * b;
                if (secondResult >= 2)
                {
                    for (int c = b; c >= 1; c--)
                    {
                        int thirdResult = secondResult - c * c;
                        if (thirdResult >= 1)
                        {
                            for (int d = c; d >= 1; d--)
                            {
                                int tmpResult = thirdResult - d * d;
                                if (tmpResult == 0)
                                {
                                    counter++;
                                    cout << "a: " << a << " b: " << b << " c: " << c << " d: " << d << endl;
                                    break;
                                }
                                else if (tmpResult > 0)
                                {
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**As I didn't had C++ by hand, I did the timing in C#.** This calculates **1221** unique combinations for `resultToReach==2000000` in about **19 seconds**.

Taking [Josay's comment](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/65163/solving-the-lazy-hobo-riddle#comment119522_65187) into account produces this

```
    int resultToReach = 200;
    int maxBorder = (int)sqrt(resultToReach);

    for (int a = maxBorder; a >= maxBorder/4; a--)
    {
        int firstResult = resultToReach - a * a;
        if (firstResult >= 3)
        {
            int firstBorder = (int)sqrt(firstResult);
            for (int b = min(a, firstBorder); b >= firstBorder/3; b--)
            {
                int secondResult = firstResult - b * b;
                if (secondResult >= 2)
                {
                    int secondBorder = (int)sqrt(secondResult);
                    for (int c = min(b, secondBorder); c >= secondBorder/2; c--)
                    {
                        int thirdResult = secondResult - c * c;
                        if (thirdResult >= 1)
                        {
                            int d = (int)sqrt(thirdResult);
                            if (d <= c && thirdResult == d * d)
                            {
                                cout << "a: " << a << " b: " << b << " c: " << c << " d: " << d << endl;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**As I didn't had C++ by hand, I did the timing in C#.** This calculates **1221** unique combinations for `resultToReach==2000000` in about **4.5 seconds**.

Answer (score 11):

One thing to consider, doing  repeated multiplications inside a loop and/or inside the loop declaration can be very expensive.  Consider the following, which puts all the squares in an array and the loops only iterate through the array.  This eliminates a lot of extra calculations.  In my tests, even with the cost of an extra loop, this resulted in about a 30% increase in speed.

```
int squares[15];
const int limit = 200;
int it_limit = 15;
for (int i = 1; i < it_limit; i++)
    squares[i] = i*i;
int temp = 0;
for (int a = 1; a < it_limit; a++)
{
    temp = squares[a];
    for (int b = a; b < it_limit; b++)
    {
        temp = squares[b] + squares[a];
        if (temp > limit)
            break;
        for (int c = b; c < it_limit; c++)
        {
            temp = squares[c] + squares[b] + squares[a];
            if (temp > limit)
                break;
            for (int d = c; d < it_limit; d++)
            {
                temp = squares[d] + squares[c] + squares[b] + squares[a];
                if (temp > limit)
                    break;
                if (temp == limit)
                    cout << "a: " << a << " b: " << b << " c: " << c << " d: " << d << "\n";
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 11):

Finding all the solutions in a low number of iterations:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <map>
#include <vector>

typedef unsigned int T;

int main()
{
    const T LIMIT = 2000000;
    std::map< T,std::vector< std::pair< T,T > > > pairs_of_squares;
    T a, b, c, d, sum_of_squares, remaining;
    unsigned long increment = 0;
    unsigned long num_results = 0;
    unsigned long index;
    std::vector< std::pair< T, T > > array_of_pairs;
    std::stringstream out;

    for ( a = 1; 2 * a * a <= LIMIT - 2; ++a )
    {
        for ( b = a; (sum_of_squares = a*a + b*b) <= LIMIT - 2; ++b )
        {
            remaining = LIMIT - sum_of_squares;
            // Check if it is possible to get another pair (c,d) such that either
            // a <= b <= c <= d or c <= d <= a <= b and, if not, ignore this pair.
            if ( a * a * 2 < remaining && remaining < b * b * 2 )
            {
                ++increment;
                continue;
            }
            pairs_of_squares[sum_of_squares].push_back( std::pair<T,T>(a,b) );

            if ( pairs_of_squares.count( remaining ) != 0 )
            {
                array_of_pairs = pairs_of_squares[ remaining ];
                for ( index = 0; index < array_of_pairs.size(); ++index )
                {
                    c = array_of_pairs[index].first;
                    d = array_of_pairs[index].second;
                    if ( b <= c )
                    {
                        out         << a
                            << ", " << b
                            << ", " << c
                            << ", " << d
                            << '\n';
                        ++num_results;
                    }
                    else if ( d <= a )
                    {
                        out         << c
                            << ", " << d
                            << ", " << a
                            << ", " << b
                            << '\n';
                        ++num_results;
                    }
                    ++increment;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ++increment;
            }
        }
    }

    std::cout << out.str()
                << num_results << " possibilities found in " << increment << " increments." << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

For a limit of 200:

```
2, 4, 6, 12
6, 6, 8, 8
2 possibilities found in 75 increments.

real    0m0.005s
user    0m0.003s
sys 0m0.002s
```

[Note: this only takes 75 iterations rather than over 1,000 to find all the possible answers.]

For a limit of 2,000,000:

```
...
104, 192, 984, 992
56, 112, 984, 1008
1221 possibilities found in 785771 increments.

real    0m0.890s
user    0m0.873s
sys 0m0.014s
```

**Explanation:**

Do not work on all 4 numbers individually - work on two pairs of numbers (a low valued pair and a high valued pair).

Start by generating a pair of numbers \$(a,b)\$ where \$a \leq b\$ and \$a^2 + b^2 \leq LIMIT - 2\$ (note: 2 is the minimum sum of squares for the other pair of numbers) and push that pair of numbers into a map.

It then checks whether the map contains another pair \$(c,d)\$ where \$c \leq d\$ and \$c^2 + d^2 = LIMIT - a^2 - b^2\$ such that either \$a \leq b \leq c \leq d\$ or \$c \leq d \leq a \leq b\$ in which case it is a valid answer and outputs it.

Then repeat for other pairs of \$(a,b)\$.

Answer (score 7):

I'm actually not OK with the assumption that the answer to the hobo question is solving `a*a+b*b+c*c+d*d = 200` in an iterative fashion.

I think it is a square root and rounding question that can be solved with a greedy algorithm.

The guy with the highest workload could do a max of `sqrt(200)` = 14.142 hours for 14.142 days. Rounded down, that'd be 14*14=196, leaving only 4 hours of work for the other 3.   That doesn't work.

Try 13... 200-(13*13)=31 for the other 3 and then check the next guy recursively, which gives the following code:

```
int find_worst_hours( int workleft, int numguys )
{
    static int num_interations = 0;
    int mine = (int)floor(sqrt((double)workleft));
    TRACE( "Num iterations = %d\n", ++num_interations );
    while( mine > 0 )   {
        int leftover = workleft - mine*mine;
        TRACE( "Guys Left %d:I would do %d, rest would do %d\n", numguys, mine, leftover );
        if ( numguys == 1 ) {
            // last guy
            if ( leftover > 0 ) {
                return -1;      // bad solution, work left over.
            } else {
                // no work left, this is a good solution.
                TRACE( "GOOD END, guy %d, work %d\n", numguys, mine );
                return mine;
            }
        } else {
            // check the rest of guys
            if ( leftover == 0 )    {
                return -1;      // bad solution, the other guys need work
            }
            int next_guys_work = find_worst_hours( leftover, numguys-1 );
            if ( next_guys_work > 0 )   {
                // valid solution
                TRACE( "GOOD PARTIAL, guy %d, work %d\n", numguys, mine );
                return mine;
            } else {
                // couldn't find a solution... try less hours
                mine--;
                // continue while loop
            }
        }

    }
    return -1;      // couldn't find solution
}
```

Which you can call once with:

```
find_worst_hours( 200, 4 );
```

And it should output:

> ```
> Num iterations = 1
> Guys Left 4:I would do 14, rest would do 4
> Num iterations = 2
> Guys Left 3:I would do 2, rest would do 0
> Guys Left 4:I would do 13, rest would do 31
> Num iterations = 3
> Guys Left 3:I would do 5, rest would do 6
> Num iterations = 4
> Guys Left 2:I would do 2, rest would do 2
> Num iterations = 5
> Guys Left 1:I would do 1, rest would do 1
> Guys Left 2:I would do 1, rest would do 5
> Num iterations = 6
> Guys Left 1:I would do 2, rest would do 1
> Guys Left 3:I would do 4, rest would do 15
> Num iterations = 7
> Guys Left 2:I would do 3, rest would do 6
> Num iterations = 8
> Guys Left 1:I would do 2, rest would do 2
> Guys Left 2:I would do 2, rest would do 11
> Num iterations = 9
> Guys Left 1:I would do 3, rest would do 2
> Guys Left 2:I would do 1, rest would do 14
> Num iterations = 10
> Guys Left 1:I would do 3, rest would do 5
> Guys Left 3:I would do 3, rest would do 22
> Num iterations = 11
> Guys Left 2:I would do 4, rest would do 6
> Num iterations = 12
> Guys Left 1:I would do 2, rest would do 2
> Guys Left 2:I would do 3, rest would do 13
> Num iterations = 13
> Guys Left 1:I would do 3, rest would do 4
> Guys Left 2:I would do 2, rest would do 18
> Num iterations = 14
> Guys Left 1:I would do 4, rest would do 2
> Guys Left 2:I would do 1, rest would do 21
> Num iterations = 15
> Guys Left 1:I would do 4, rest would do 5
> Guys Left 3:I would do 2, rest would do 27
> Num iterations = 16
> Guys Left 2:I would do 5, rest would do 2
> Num iterations = 17
> Guys Left 1:I would do 1, rest would do 1
> Guys Left 2:I would do 4, rest would do 11
> Num iterations = 18
> Guys Left 1:I would do 3, rest would do 2
> Guys Left 2:I would do 3, rest would do 18
> Num iterations = 19
> Guys Left 1:I would do 4, rest would do 2
> Guys Left 2:I would do 2, rest would do 23
> Num iterations = 20
> Guys Left 1:I would do 4, rest would do 7
> Guys Left 2:I would do 1, rest would do 26
> Num iterations = 21
> Guys Left 1:I would do 5, rest would do 1
> Guys Left 3:I would do 1, rest would do 30
> Num iterations = 22
> Guys Left 2:I would do 5, rest would do 5
> Num iterations = 23
> Guys Left 1:I would do 2, rest would do 1
> Guys Left 2:I would do 4, rest would do 14
> Num iterations = 24
> Guys Left 1:I would do 3, rest would do 5
> Guys Left 2:I would do 3, rest would do 21
> Num iterations = 25
> Guys Left 1:I would do 4, rest would do 5
> Guys Left 2:I would do 2, rest would do 26
> Num iterations = 26
> Guys Left 1:I would do 5, rest would do 1
> Guys Left 2:I would do 1, rest would do 29
> Num iterations = 27
> Guys Left 1:I would do 5, rest would do 4
> Guys Left 4:I would do 12, rest would do 56
> Num iterations = 28
> Guys Left 3:I would do 7, rest would do 7
> Num iterations = 29
> Guys Left 2:I would do 2, rest would do 3
> Num iterations = 30
> Guys Left 1:I would do 1, rest would do 2
> Guys Left 2:I would do 1, rest would do 6
> Num iterations = 31
> Guys Left 1:I would do 2, rest would do 2
> Guys Left 3:I would do 6, rest would do 20
> Num iterations = 32
> Guys Left 2:I would do 4, rest would do 4
> Num iterations = 33
> Guys Left 1:I would do 2, rest would do 0
> GOOD END, guy 1, work 2
> GOOD PARTIAL, guy 2, work 4
> GOOD PARTIAL, guy 3, work 6
> GOOD PARTIAL, guy 4, work 12
> ```

So it took only 33 iterations and we found the answer 2,4,6,12.  This should be VERY fast to calculate.

Comment: And how about 6^2 + 6^2 + 8^2 + 8^2 ?

Comment: Could you change the algorithm to determine all the possible solutions? As it is right now it exits at the first solution which is not what the OP asked for.

Comment: I don't think 6,6,8,8 is a valid solution to the hobo question since the smart guy wants to do less work than the others, not the same. :)

Comment: Tibos - I'll do that if I have time, but since it is a greedy algorithm, and this guy is a greedy hobo, the first solution is the only solution in his mind.

Comment: Except that it's clearly stated `The riddle is to determine the possible ways to divide up the work according to the preceding scheme.`  Notice it says possible ways not the best way.

Comment: @tinstaafl But "the possible ways" implies all of them, not just one (which would be "a possible way").

Comment: @DavidRicherby - Which is exactly the point I was making.