# Listing the representations of integer M as a sum of three squares M = x^2 + y^2 + z^2

Tags: python, array, combinatorics, integer

I am trying a number as the sum of 3 squares.  For my particular project I will require a complete list since the next step is to compute nearest neighbors ([here](http://arxiv.org/abs/1204.0134v2)).

In any case we'd like to find \$ M = x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \$ in all possible ways.  Here's what I wrote in Python:

```
M = 1062437
m = int(np.sqrt(M))

x = np.arange(int(np.sqrt(m)))
y = M - x**2

sq = [(i,j, int(np.sqrt(M - i**2 - j**2))) for i in range(m) for j in range(m) if i**2 + j**2 in y]
```

This is easy to explain in pseudocode.

- build a list of remainders \$\{ M - k^2 : 0 \leq k \leq \sqrt{M} \}\$
- loop over all possible \$0 < i,j < \sqrt{M} \$ check that \$i^2 + j^2 \$ is in the list

This is one of several possible strategies.  In my case, I don't even need a fixed `M` it could be a range, such as `10**6 < M < 10**6 + 10*4`.

I do not  mind looping over values of `M` at this point. Can we recycle our computations somehow?

Comment: Could you clarify what you're asking, please?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, does this have any real world application?

Comment: @jonrsharpe 1) is this good python and algorithms?  2) if I let M run over a range if there a way to avoid computing `i^2 + j^2` over and over?

Comment: @BrunoCosta these might appear in cryptography or coding theory.  Point sets and nearest neighbor algorithms appear all over.  machine learning, digitals maps, front-end, back-end.

Comment: You may want to first make sure your number is not in [sequence A004215 in OEIS](http://oeis.org/A004215), see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre's_three-square_theorem) for details.

Comment: @Jaime I am not computing the number... I need a list of the triples themselves

Comment: I understand that, but there are no triples themselves for numbers in A004215, and hence no point in searching for them...

Comment: @Jaime https://oeis.org/A005875 we are counting the triples (x, y, z) whose squares sum to M.

Comment: Maybe I am not explaining myself properly, but unless you have such a filter upstream, you should add something like the following to your function: `M_copy = M; rem = 0; while not rem: M_copy, rem = divmod(M_copy, 4); if M_copy % 8 == 7: return []` It will save you lots of pointless iterations for the cost of a few divisions.

Comment: @Jaime Perhaps you can post a more detailed answer.  Here $M$ is the input, and I am computing the values `x,y,z` such that `x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = M`

Answer (score 3):

You might be interested in [this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/65163/solving-the-lazy-hobo-riddle/).

While looking for solution to

$$ x^{2} + y^{2} + z^{2} = M $$

you can assume

$$ x  \leq y  \leq z$$.

and perform rotation if needed afterward.

This is good because, you can start iterating over `x` in a smaller range. You know that

$$ M = x^{2} + y^{2} + z^{2} \ge x^{2} + x^{2} + x^{2}  = 3 * x^{2}$$

, therefore $$x \le sqrt(M / 3)$$

Similarly, when iterating over `y`, you can start at `x`and go up to a smaller higer bound because we have :

$$ M = x^{2} + y^{2} + z^{2} \ge x^{2} + y^{2} + y^{2}  = x^{2} + 2 * y^{2}$$

, therefore $$x \le y \le sqrt((M - x^{2})/ 2)$$

Then, when once `x` and `y` are fixed, you don't need to iterate over `z` : just compute

$$ z = sqrt(M - x^{2} - y^{2}) $$

and check that it is indeed an integer.

Here's a proof-of-concept piece of code : I've altered your code a bit to be able to compare the results you originally had with the one I get :

```
sq = set(tuple(sorted([i,j, int(np.sqrt(M - i**2 - j**2))])) for i in range(m) for j in range(m) if i**2 + j**2 in y)
print(len(sq))


sol = []
lim_x = int(np.sqrt(M/3))
for x in range(1 + lim_x):
    rem_x = M - x*x
    lim_y = int(np.sqrt(rem_x / 2))
    for y in range(x, 1 + lim_y):
        rem_y = rem_x - y*y
        z = int(np.sqrt(rem_y))
        if z*z == rem_y:
            assert x <= y <= z
            assert x*x + y*y + z*z == M
            sol.append((x, y, z))
print(len(sol))

assert all(s in sol for s in sq)
```

You have 26 different ordered solutions out of the 290 I found (in a smaller time range).

Finally, you might be able to adapt the equations above (and the code written from it) if you want to handle ranges of M values.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have np (I assume numpy) installed. So I tried pure Python. I tried to store `i,j,i**2+j**2` into a list of tuples and then reuse it later. That made it slower than your code. I also tried `(i,j)` as dict key and `i**2+j**2` as value. That did not help either.

The only thing that made it faster was to have y as a `set`.

```
m = int(math.sqrt(M))
x = range(int(math.sqrt(m)))
y = set([M - x**2 for x in x])
return [(i,j, int(math.sqrt(M - i**2 - j**2))) for i in range(m) for j in range(m) if i**2 + j**2 in y]
```

Answer (score 0):

- Code uses variables `x`, `i` and `j` instead of the `x`, `y` and `z` from the problem description. It would be clearer to use the same.
- Calculating `sqrt(m)` looks like a bug because `m = sqrt(M)` already.
- You could avoid computing the squares over and over again in the list comprehension by keeping `x**2` in a variable and making `i` and `j` loop over it.
- You could use `for j in range(i, m)` to avoid checking the same pair of numbers in reverse. If you need all the permutations of each solution, generate the reversed version at a later stage.
- Checking `in y` on an array requires a linear search. Even though the search is implemented in fast C code, a Python `set` is faster when the array is large enough.